# no known conversion for argument 1 - Passing 'this' to a method

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get hands on C++. Sorry if the post already exists, that's could be because I don't have the necessary C++ background to put the exact words on it.

I'm creating a class to handle math vectors. So I have a `Point` struct, and a `Vector` struct. I want to be able to create an instance of a `Vector` by giving two instances of `Point` to a method.

I posted the code in this gist : https://gist.github.com/benoitjupille/9bd759042e201d0e8b3c76b708467fb5

This code is not compiling, I got this :

```
In file included from /home/bjupille/code/games/Math/Math.ino:2:0:
/tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Point.h: In member function 'Benov::Vector2D Benov::Point::between(Benov::Point)':
Point.h:15:60: error: no matching function for call to 'Benov::Vector2D::between(Benov::Point*, Benov::Point&)'
         Vector2D vector = Vector2D::between(this, point);
                                                        ^
In file included from /tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Point.h:4:0,
             from /home/bjupille/code/games/Math/Math.ino:2:
/tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Vector2D.h:22:25: note: candidate: static Benov::Vector2D Benov::Vector2D::between(Point, Point)
     static Vector2D between(Point a, Point b)
                     ^~~~~~~
/tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Vector2D.h:22:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Benov::Point*' to 'Point'
```

Could you please give me some leads on what is happening here ?

Comment: `this` is a `Point*`, not a `Point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`between` is defined as this:

```
    static Vector2D between(Point a, Point b){...}
```

You are calling it like this from `Point` implementation:

```
    Vector2D vector = Vector2D::between(this, point);
```

`this` is a pointer to a `Point` in it's current context -- `between` doesn't take a pointer to a `Point`, it takes a `Point`. So you need to dereference the pointer:

```
    Vector2D vector = Vector2D::between(*this, point);
```

Once you do this and compile, you will get one more error. Add this to your `Vector2D.h`

```
struct Point; // <-- add this right before the struct definition
struct Vector2D
{

    float x;
    float y;
    //....
}
```

The reason you have to do that is because `Vector2D` doesn't know what a `Point` is because of compilation order (there is a circular reference, `Point` needs `Vector2D` and `Vector2D` needs `Point`). We are going to put that there to let the compiler know that... yes... we know what it will be eventually. (That's probably a bad explanation, but you may get the jist.)

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I tried this what you said, but got the same. Don't you think it could be related to namespace ?

Comment: @Benoit -- You got the *exact* same error? Are you doing it in more than one spot? The error says `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Benov::Point*' to 'Point'` It's impossible to do `*this` and get that same error.

Comment: Yes look : 

     /tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Vector2D.h:22:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Benov::Point' to 'Point'

Comment: @Benoit -- ok -- it *is* different -- now it's a namespace issue.

Comment: The compiler talks about `Benov::Point to Point`

Comment: Ok @Andy, thanks. Would you have any leads for this too please ?

Comment: Was about to write another anwser, but you beat to finding the circular dependency :) So I'd like to add a detail here, that `Vector2D between(Point a, Point b)` will need to take references `Vector2D between(const Point &a, const Point &b)` since you can't take forward declared classes by value.

Comment: Damned, I'm so confused, still not working : `/tmp/arduino_build_457310/sketch/Vector2D.h:22:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Benov::Point' to 'const Point&`

Comment: If you are a beginner take baby steps. Don't use namespaces until you are more familiar with other aspects of the language. C++ is complicated.

Comment: @Benoit -- Did you get it to work? Sorry, last night as soon as i updated that i went to bed. If you didn't, we can work on it in SO chat.

Comment: Yes thank you @Andy, I actually used what you told me.